# Hosting the PHP API in nginx with a reverse proxy

Tags: php, nginx, proxy

My angularjs application would interact with the REST API using AJAX calls. So I wanted to add a reverse proxy which would allow those calls to work with cross-origin resource sharing(CORS), but they don't make it through.

Here is the API server side configuration:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  www.test.com;
  root /data/backend/static/;
  index index.html;
  charset utf-8;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/backend.access.log  main;

  location / {
    root /data/backend/static/;
    index index.html;
  }

  location /api/ {
    alias /data/backend/api/public/;
    index index.html;
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php;
    if (!-f $request_filename)
      rewrite /api/(.*) /api/index.php/$1;
  }

  location ~ \.php($|/) {
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    #fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /data/backend/api/public/index.php;#$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
  }
```

Here is client side configuration of nginx, according as [here](http://www.sep.com/sep-blog/2014/08/20/hosting-the-node-api-in-nginx-with-a-reverse-proxy/):

```
upstream see_api {
    server    119.119.119.119:80;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /Users/a123/Work/backend_static/src;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        rewrite ^/api/?(.*) /$1 break;

        proxy_pass http://see_api;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

And the result is a 404 error:

[image]